# Which sentence is more natural? Can we use "dated" or "on" before a specific date?

Tags: sentence-construction

> We sent you a letter dated December 20, 2020.

or

> We sent you a letter on December 20, 2021.

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things.

> We sent you a letter dated December 20

means that a letter was sent, and the letter has "December 20" printed on it. *Usually* this means it was sent on or about December 20th, but it may have been sent several days before or after then—there is no guarantee. The sending of the letter and the date on the letter are not connected, grammatically speaking.

> We sent you a letter on December 20

means the letter was sent, and the sending of the letter occurred on December 20th. Now the action and the time are connected in the sentence; the time mentioned is when the action took place. The letter may have "December 20" printed on it, or it may not.